Is there a wildcard option to bundle all TypeScript or HTML files in Bun?
Is there a wildcard option to tell Bun to bundle all files of a specific type?
Here is what I have now:
// bun.build.js

import html from 'bun-plugin-html';

await Bun.build({
  entrypoints: ['./index.html', './page1.html', './page2.html', ..., './page1000.html', ...],
  publicPath: "public",
  sourcemap: "inline",
  outdir: './public',
  plugins: [
    html()
  ],
});

Is there a way to all HTML files or all TypeScript files in a directory?
I'm guessing it would look something like this:
// bun.build.js

import html from 'bun-plugin-html';

await Bun.build({
  indir: ['./public'], // pseudo code input directory
  fileTypes: ['html', 'ts'], // pseudo code compile all files with html or ts extension
  sourcemap: "inline",
  outdir: './public',
  plugins: [
    html()
  ],
});

I just found something in the guide. It says I can bundle a a single typescript file by calling bun run index.ts. Is it possible to do something like, bun run *.ts?
UPDATE:
I have been calling bun run start and now I think it's supposed to be, bun bun.build.js.

I'm the creator of bun-plugin-html. As far as I know, there is no way of using a wildcard with the Bun.build method. Instead, I would recommend using Bun.Glob to select all HTML files, they provide that as an entry point array.
Ex.
import { Glob } from "bun";
import html from 'bun-plugin-html';

const glob = new Glob("**/*.html");
const entrypoints = await Array.fromAsync(glob.scan({ cwd: './src' })) // Creates an array of all files in ./src with a .html file extension

await Bun.build({
    entrypoints,
    publicPath: "public",
    outdir: './public',
    plugins: [
        html()
    ],
});

Do note that this will generate separate html files for each entrypoint.
